# Convenience function defined for debugging with ipdb in Python

Tags: python, debugging, pdb, ipdb

At the top of my Python scripts I have defined the following convenience function for debugging with ipdb:

```
def bp():
    import ipdb
    ipdb.set_trace()
```

So when I want to debug in a certain point I can write:

```
bp()
```

instead of having to write

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

(I prefer not to import ipdb unless needed).

The problem with this approach is that when entering pdb I land inside the function bp(), so I have to press 'u' to go to the relevant part of the code:

```
> /path/to/script.py(15)bp()
      14     import ipdb
 ---> 15     ipdb.set_trace()
      16 

ipdb> u
```

Is there a way I could have a similar approach, but landing directly into the relevant part of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to change the active frame in a breakpoint defined by a call to ipdb.set_trace() is as follows:

```
def bp():
    import ipdb
    import sys
    ipdb.set_trace(sys._getframe().f_back)
```

The same approach does not seem to work for pdb with a simple renaming, but the following seems to work:

```
def bp():
    from pdb import Pdb
    import sys
    Pdb().set_trace(sys._getframe().f_back)
```

I tested this in python 3.5, but not in other python versions.

Comment: Good! It also works if the "import sys" is included within the definition bp()

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect the observation about `import sys`. Thanks!